# Wamp Put online

Tags: ip-address, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have wamp installed on my pc. and i have used the put online option. But when i visit my ip address. it doesnt visit my local host. on my desktop it used to happen. when i got my laptop. not it redirects to my Router Modems login page.

How to set wamp to access it via my ip address.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to forward port 80 on your router to your local IP address (like `192.168.0.3`), port 80. (and 443 if you intent to use HTTPS).

Comment: It depends on your router. What kind of router do you have? (include model name if possible)

Comment: See http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/UTStarcom/WA3002-G4/default.htm